# Get only name of lists from YAML in Python

Tags: python, yaml

Let's say I have a yaml file with the following structure:

```
root:
  uncle:
  children:
    son:
      grandson:
        bob:
        charlie:
    daughter:
      granddaughter:
        tamara:
        julia:
```

and all I want is to display only descendants of children, without its own descendants. To clarify, I want to display only:

```
son: 
daughter:
```

I wrote following code snippet:

```
import yaml

    with open('sample.yaml', 'r') as list:
        children_list = yaml.safe_load(list)
        print(children_list["root"]["children"])
```

but it prints me everything:

```
 children:
    son:
      grandson:
        bob:
        charlie:
    daughter:
      granddaughter:
        tamara:
        julia:
```

How can I fix my code?

Comment: The posted output  us not what your code produces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand then you need the keys, 
just add children_list["root"]["children"].keys()

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your code by accurately describing what you want to print.  First of all, your `yaml` loaded structure is

```
{'root': {
    'uncle': None
    'children': {
        'son': {
            'grandson': {
                 'bob': None,
                 'charlie': None}},
        'daughter': {
            'granddaughter': {
                 'tamara': None,
                 'julia': None}}}}}
```

This is a nested dict.  Your code asks for the entry ['root']['children'], which is the structure

```
{'son': {'grandson': {'bob': None, 'charlie': None}},
 'daughter': {'granddaughter': {'tamara': None, 'julia': None}}}
```

If all you want is the labels (keys), then you need to extract those keys from this structure:

```
for k in children_struct["root"]["children"].keys():
    print(k)
```

This will print the labels -- but without the trailing colon, as that is a syntactic separator, not part of the stored structure.